# File storage in azure. A generic error occured in GDI+

Tags: c#, azure, system.drawing

I'm saving file as:

```
var i2 = new Bitmap(image);
i2.Save(Server.MapPath(@"~\Images\Ads\" + filename));
```

I'm getting error:

> "System.Runtime.InteropServices.ExternalException (0x80004005): A
>   generic error occurred in GDI+.  at System.Drawing.Image.Save(String
>   filename, ImageCodecInfo encoder, EncoderParameters encoderParams)  at
>   System.Drawing.Image.Save(String filename, ImageFormat format)  at
>   System.Drawing.Image.Save(String filename)

How can I check that `Images` and `Ad` folders exist?

And where my images are saved? Can I see `Ad` directory and all files in it?

**Note:** I want to use azure simple file storage to store files temporary. I don't want to use azure blob.

Comment: You should edit your question with more details, such as where you're running your code (VM? web/worker role? Web app?).

Comment: Hi @Irfan, we're having the exact same problem with Azure, but only when we publish from specific computers - did you ever find a solution? It looks like a slot can get 'poisened' and then GDI+ never works again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was getting his error because my `Ads` directory does not exist.

Azure does not create directories by itself, if it does not exist. I simply used this:

```
    Directory.CreateDirectory(Server.MapPath(@"~\Images\Ads\");
```

It creates a directory if it does not exist.

Answer (score 0):

You can view images in Kudu console application directory, if it is uploaded else you will get detailed error logs there

[Using KUDU with Microsoft Azure Web Apps](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/benjaminperkins/2014/03/24/using-kudu-with-windows-azure-web-sites/)

for general **flexible** shared file storage, try using Azure Blob Storage -

Comment: Can't I view my file system like in godaddy. In your link, the path is specified as `D:\Home`? But my website is on azure server

Comment: Why should I use KUDU?? I just want to get rid of above error

Comment: To access it, simply go to {yoursite}.scm.azurewebsites.net, and click on Debug Console at the top.

Answer (score 0):

Though this wasn't your question, be careful with this solution.  As soon as Azure needs to reboot your box (hardware failure, updates) it'll spin up your site on a new server, and your `Images\Ads` folder will be gone.  You would be better leveraging Azure Blob storage for this.  See how Scott Hanselman does this in his video: http://www.hanselman.com/blog/PennyPinchingVideoMovingMyWebsitesImagesToTheAzureCDNAndUsingACustomDomain.aspx